# Power Injector for 30 pin iPod cable

Tags: ipod

I have an iPod that uses a 30-pin dock connector. I have a vehicle that has a 30-pin cable built-in to connect the iPod to the vehicle's stereo. But the stereo does not provide power to the iPod. Is there an adapter so that I can plug the vehicle cable into adapter (for data) and a USB cable into the adapter (for power)? I intend to get power from the vehicles DC outlet and an adapter to convert to USB.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the wrong idea here.

The 30-pin connector for an iPhone has power and data ports. Your car clearly is not serving power to the power port of your iPhone connector. To do this manually, I'd recommend *taking a look at the link below*. It is based on giving power to a VGA accessory in order to power up the iPhone with this same plug. You are basically trying to do the same thing with a music adapter for your car.

http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1200699

Hope this helps! (If it does, mark it as the answer. Thx.)

Comment: I don't have the wrong idea. My idea is to combine power and data from two separate sources using an adapter. I know clearly what I want, I just don't know if an adapter/Y-cable for this exists. If one doesn't exists, then yeah I'll have to solder one together similar to the guy in the link you found.

Comment: Oh, alright... If you're just looking for an adapter, then why did you ask it here?

Comment: Same reason everyone else posts on a Stack Exchange site. I was looking for a solution to a problem.

Comment: This site is for problems and solutions, not product recommendations. I'd take a good look at this site's rules if I were you.

Comment: Anyway, glad you figured it out. God bless!

Answer (score 0):

Ah, found what I'm looking for. I originally searched for "40 pin power injector" and didn't get any obvious good hits on Google. But it turns out I should have searched for "30 pin power injector".

CableJive dockStubz+ seems to be the product I was looking for.

Comment: Rules stated in http://apple.stackexchange.com/tour : Questions that might seem on-topic but aren't include shopping or buying recommendations for hardware, accessories like bags and cases.

Comment: Don't post questions involving shopping.

Comment: While this question did end up involving a "shopping" solution, you're still free to post a "non shopping" solution.